# Manually launched Spring Boot application from .jar not working properly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jar, spring-boot

The problem is when I run .jar file(Spring Boot MVC app) from Intellij IDEA, application works fine, but when I try to run same file from the command line, template resolver cannot find template(.html) files. And this seems to be reasonable since when I opened .jar with file archiver I did not find any traces of that files.

How Intellij make it work proper? And how can I do the same?
My project structure:
[image]

here they are, in '/templates' folder

.jar file opened in archiver:

[image]

As I said, there is no .html files, so how Intellij add them when running .jar?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.vlad.pet.contactlist</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-ALPHA</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>web-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>


  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vlad.pet.contactlist</groupId>
      <artifactId>model</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-inmemory</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal Spring Boot application built from http://start.spring.io would show the templates folder within the `src/main/resources`. This is because by default the contents of that folder are made available to the classpath and packaged at the root of the jar file. I am guessing you modified the project in IntelliJ to also pick up the `src/main/webapp` directory. Unfortunately that doesn't work when it comes to packaging the jar. You would need to work with the maven resources plugin to specify the additional directory to be included in the jar file.

My recommendation is to go to start.spring.io. Select `Web` and `Thymeleaf` as dependencies and then download the zip file. When you look in that file you will see the default structure along with settings for any plugins to make it work. Mirror that structure within you application.

If you don't have the ability to change the project structure then check out the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) for specifics on how to add those directories.

Comment: Well, seems like that "Intellij automatically pick up files" thing will remain mystery. But I'm grateful for your help. In my case this problem was just a little trick: after moving templates to "resources" I configured tempateResolver prefix like "/templates/", but should: "classpath:/templates/"

Answer (score 1):

You can see what exactly IntelliJ is doing, by looking at first line in its console after running app. There should be full command called by IntelliJ.

And how .jar is build? Maven/Gradle? maybe there's some problem with pom/build script

*It should be comment, but my reputation is too low*

Comment: The first line is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar path/to/app.jar. I use: java -jar app.jar. I bet it's the same?

Comment: actually I checked this one and I'm 90% sure this line is waaaaaay longer, It's so long I can't publish this one in comment so I'll use [hastebin](http://hastebin.com/darokaquno.m)

Comment: I checked my 'run' window, and I can say 2nd line and all following are info from loggers, like: 23:27:15,571 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy] and so on @krzychek

Comment: First one could be wrapped or something..

Anyway, I just realized that's spring boot and so you can use:
*  `mvn spring-boot:run` to run application
*  `mvn spring-boot:repackage` to repackage
*  `mvn spring-boot:help` for help

you can add repackage goal to pom like it is done [here in example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the plugin to generate an executable jar:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

After building the jar (e.g. mvn clean install), you can run the jar as java -jar ./target/project.jar

Comment: The repackage goal is bound to the package lifecycle by default. You don't need to list the execution explicitly.